# How to prevent react-native-web-webview to repeatedly ask permission to access mic permission IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, webview, react-native-webview

I have used react-native-webview in my app and even though i have accepted permission to microphone for websiteit asking every few minuets, i couldn't find solution anywhere